Converting a USB HID K/M Composite Device to a USB HID Compound Device (or Two Seperate K/M Devices)
I want to connect a USB composite device (Raritan KX4-101) with keyboard and mouse descriptors to a USB matrix switch with a very picky HID keyboard and mouse emulation (Extron SMX USB).
From what I found out so far, the USB matrix switch's HID emulation only recognizes standard (single address) HID input devices correctly. They are also recognized when they are connected to a hub, so I guess compound keyboard and mouse combinations would also be recognized, but I have no such device to test this, probably because most (all?) combined devices are implemented as composite devices.
The only approach for the solution of my problem I could find was using PS/2 as an intermediate protocol by using a USB to PS/2 converter (ATEN CV10KM), which converts to two separate PS/2 keyboard and mouse connections, and then converting it back to two separate USB devices. Unfortunately, all PS/2 to USB converters I was testing are also implemented as composite devices because they convert PS/2 keyboard and mouse to USB simultaneously.
Are there PS/2 to USB converters available, specialized for keyboard or mouse, which are implemented as non-composite devices, ideally low-speed?
Or, even better, are there any more elegant solutions which can do the conversion from composite to two separate devices or a compound device directly?

talk to Extron tech support

Extron won't talk to end users, especially not about discontinued products.
